# Play Scala Framework : type mismatch scala.concurrent.Future[Object] [error] required: scala.concurrent.Future[play.api.mvc.Result]

Tags: scala, playframework

I have one compilation error that I cannot solved yet. It's about an action adding a new patient into mongo if he is not already in the database. First the model :

```
 case class PatientData(id : String)

 object PatientData {
    implicit val PatientDataFormat = Json.format[PatientData]
  }
```

The function searching the patient in mongo :

```
 def findPatientById(mode : String, id : String) : Future[Option[PatientData]] = {
    val collection = getPatientCollection(mode)
    collection.find(Json.obj("id" -> id)).one[PatientData]
  }
```

The Play action :

```
def create(patientId: String) = Action.async(parse.json) { request =>
    val token = "dummy"
    isAuthorized(token) match { // always return Some(thing) 
      case None => Future.successful(Unauthorized("Invalid token " + token))
      case Some(_) =>
        request.body.validate[PatientData] map { 
          patientData =>
          findPatientById(mode,patientId) map { finded =>
            finded match {
              case Some(_) => Future.successful(NotAcceptable("The patient is already exist."))
              case None =>
                Logger.info("Create the patient .. ")
                Future.successful(Created)
            }
          }
        } getOrElse {
          Future.successful(BadRequest)
        }
    }
```

I know that I can solve this problem using a call to `Await.result` in the function `findPatientById` but I want avoid this solution and let the `Future` doing his job. The problem is that I get a compilation error :

```
[error] /home/afk/git/bioserenity/bioserenity-backend/app/controllers/MedataController.scala:90: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : scala.concurrent.Future[Object]
[error]  required: scala.concurrent.Future[play.api.mvc.Result]
[error]         } getOrElse {
[error]           ^
[error] one error found
[error] (compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
```

Anyone have an idea to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably try to use

```
findPatientById(mode,patientId) flatMap { ...
```

instead of original line. Here, the `map` call is replaced by `flatMap` so that the instance returned by that block of code is `Future[Something]` rather than `Future[Future[Something]]`.

Comment: Thank for the fix :)